# Bare minimum infrastructure to keep a fleet of IoT devices running and ensure updates to OS and applications?

Tags: security, linux, system-architecture, gsm

The number of currently available tools to run and maintain a fleet of IoT devices is staggering. To compare all is not feasible, however a list of the bare minimum required features to look for would speed up the process of finding *the one*.

Assuming the following requirements:

- Fleet of 50+ devices (RPi or similar)
- After initial setup, only remote access is possible
- High uptime and active monitoring is desirable (GUI/custom notifications)
- Secure OS incl. updates when necessary
- Updates for running applications
- Optionally run untrusted apps containerized
- Communication over GSM with private backend
- VPN support

With that in mind, what are the key criteria to fulfill when looking for deployment and management infrastructure? What architecture decisions must be considered?

Please showcase with examples if possible.

Comment: Just to be clear, by VPN support you mean that your rPis will be running on a VPN independent from the infrastructure, or that the VPN should be built into the infrastructure?

Comment: Generally VPN as part of the infrastructure for improved security, but with the option to have some client applications hop on a different one (e.g. proprietary software that requires its own VPN).

Answer (score 1):

AWS has their solution to this as [Greengrass](https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/)
Others have their own, I'm sure. Lots of examples on that website.
"Bare minimum" is tricky! Its like asking: Here's what I need. Is there something that's an exact fit ? Well, maybe AWS is more but maybe you'll get charged for only what you need, if you're careful.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Greengrass seems like a great fit if you're already invested in other AWS products.